# Google Search app cannot find installed apps

Tags: google-search

My Android phone is Samsung Galaxy Grand (I9082). I rooted it and flashed Google apps into it. Everything works well except for this: Google Search just cannot find installed apps for me. I believe my settings are correct.

Here are some screenshots:

[image] [image]

As you can see in the screenshots, I have Kindle installed, but Google Search simply cannot find it for me. Actually, it cannot find any installed apps for me.

Any idea what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score -1):

This is just Google wanting you to use the search box to generate paid clicks for them. It doesn't make them any money to help you find apps on your device, the search box is there for a reason - to send you to the web and click on ads.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question since Google Search is, in fact, able to search for local data on phones, as shown in [this](https://websetnet.net/how-to-hide-apps-from-google-search-in-android/) and [this](https://9to5google.com/2016/08/30/google-in-apps-search-mode/) articles.

Comment: actually I found if you pull UP on the search bar, there's a separate search which is the built in phone apps search. nicely hidden tho!